# What exactly is the difference between “Max“ and “Super“ setting in ECC BIOS setting of Asus M5A78L-M/USB3 motherboard?

Tags: memory, bios, ecc, asus

The manual says only:

> ECC Configuration
>
> ECC Mode [Disabled]
>
> Enables or disables the DRAM ECC that allows the hardware to report and correct memory errors automatically.
>
> Configuration options: [Disabled] [Basic] [Good] [Super] [Max] [User]“

Which says absolutely nothing about the particular difference between **Super** and **Max**.

Comment: There is normally a panel that describes the active (selected) feature within the firmware itself.  Does this not exist on your system?

Comment: “Super“ option is noted that scrub rate is dynamic and all memory is scubbed in 8 hours. How exactly is it different from “Max“ option (which does not have a comment)?

Comment: Based on the name itself, I would assume max, would be the static (maximum) scrub rate the system supports.

Comment: Thank you very much @Ramhound that gives some clarity

Answer (score 0):

Official answer from ASUS Customer Service:

> It relates to Error checking - and the capacity it does it, max being max and super being a lot
>
> It is typically a trade off in performance the more it checks for bit errors

Comment: Eh, that's a non-answer. This only tells us that _max_ does more error checking than _super_, that's what we already know from the order of choices and their names.

Comment: yeah, their answers (not only this one, I have asked other things as well) are pretty lame and non-detailed as if they don't know the answer and don't care to check and just try generic guess instead of being precise with the question